# How to implement third Nelson's rule with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to implement [Nelson's rules](https://www.leansixsigmadefinition.com/glossary/nelson-rules/) using Pandas. One of them is giving me grief, specifically number 3:

[image: nelson_rule_3]

Using some example data:

`data = pd.DataFrame({"values":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,5,6,5,3]})`

|  | values |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 6 | 7 |
| 7 | 5 |
| 8 | 6 |
| 9 | 5 |
| 10 | 3 |

My first approach was to use a rolling window to check if they are in/decreasing with `diff()>0` and use this to identify "hits" on the rule:

`(data.diff()>0).rolling(6).sum()==6`

This correctly identifies the end values (1=True, 0=False):

|  | values | correct /desired |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 0 | 0 |
| 8 | 0 | 0 |
| 9 | 0 | 0 |
| 10 | 0 | 0 |

This misses the first points (which are part of the run) because rolling is a look behind. Given this rule requires 6 points in a row, I essentially need to evaluate for a given point the 6 possible windows it can fall in and then mark it as true if it is part of any window in which the points are consecutively in/decreasing.

I can think of how I could do this with some custom Python code with `iterrows()` or `apply`. I am, however keen to keep this performant, so want to limit myself to the Panda's API.

How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following toy dataframe (an extended version of yours):

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({"values": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 5, 3, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 4, 3, 8, 9, 10, 2]})
```

Here is one way to do it with Pandas [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) and [interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html):

```py
# Find consecutive values
df["check"] = (df.diff() > 0).rolling(6).sum()
df["check"] = df["check"].mask(df["check"] < 6).mask(df["check"] >= 6, 1)

# Mark values
df = df.interpolate(limit_direction="backward", limit=5).fillna(0)
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output
    values  check
0        1      0
1        2      1
2        3      1
3        4      1
4        5      1
5        6      1
6        7      1
7        5      0
8        6      0
9        5      0
10       3      0
11      11      1
12      12      1
13      13      1
14      14      1
15      15      1
16      16      1
17       4      0
18       3      0
19       8      0
20       9      0
21      10      0
22       2      0
```

Comment: This solves the problem but still has an explicit for loop, is there anyway to remove that ?

Comment: Right. I've removed the for-loop and also the call to apply (since it is a for-loop in disguise). Cheers.